# AFnetworking Cancel Specific Upload process

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

I m uploading multiple image my images on server, URL is same for all.
Following is the code.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;

manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

NSDictionary *parameters = @{KEY: VALUE};
NSString *imageUrl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/user/upload/item",BASE_SERVER_ADDRESS];


AFHTTPRequestOperation *op =    [manager POST:imageUrl parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"IMG00%i.png",count];

    [formData appendPartWithFileData:_imageData name:@"files" fileName:imageName mimeType:@"image/png"];

} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"Success: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, error);
}];
[op setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    double percentDone = (double)totalBytesWritten / (double)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
    //Upload Progress bar here
    NSLog(@"progress updated(percentDone) : %f", percentDone);

}];
[op start];
```

I upload 10 images parallel and get the progress of each image individual. Now I want to cancel the specific uploading image, like 5th image. 
How can I get the Operation of that image. 
`operationQueue` has only `NSOperation` inside it. How will I know that specific `NSOperation` is the one I want to cancel. 
Thanks.

Comment: Does _imageData contains all your images? 
Actually, you don't need to call `[op start]` as at this moment your operation was already added to `manager` operation queue and started by it internally.

Comment: No, imageData contains only one image, so that I can get the progress of each image individually.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store operation you need to cancel in a variable, and later call `[op cancel]`.